# How to set up 2 try-all parameters in one route MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there anyway that I can use 2 try-all parameters in one same RouteBase?

ie: I currently have route : "media/{*key}" which is a customised route that grab media file from S3

for SEO purpose: I need to set up another route "media/{*key}/{*name}" which pointing to the same S3 resource as above, but having a name append at the end

Currently I created a customized "StorageServiceRoute" in handling the routing.

However

```
var innerRoute = new Route(_routeUrl, this);
```

is not capable having 2 try-catch in _routURL ("media/{*key}/{*name}"), and I having error as below:

> A catch-all parameter can only appear as the last segment of the route
>   URL.

is there any good way of handling this in routing? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom route:

```
public class MediaRoute : Route
{
    public MediaRoute()
        : base(
            "media/{*catchall}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index"
            }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()
        )
    {
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var rd = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (rd == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var catchall = rd.GetRequiredString("catchall");
        var tokens = catchall.Split(new[] { '/' }, 2);
        if (tokens.Length > 0)
        {
            rd.Values["key"] = tokens[0];
        }
        if (tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            rd.Values["name"] = tokens[1];
        }

        return rd;
    }
}
```

which could be registered in `Global.asax`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add("media", new MediaRoute());

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your route definition has a problem

You route URL definition has a problem of when does one catch-all parameter end and the next one starts:

```
"media/{*key}/{*name}"
```

If the first one can have an arbitrary number of segments. So does the second one. If your route can have another static segment within, then things would be simpler. Ie.:

```
"media/{*key}/something/{*name}"
```

In this case you could either write your own custom route, or use the one I've written. You can find all the details on [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html).